# How does the following increment in address work ..

Tags: c

```
$ cat try1.c

#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
        int arr[]={1,2,3,4};
        printf("%lu--%lu--%lu--%lu\n", arr, arr+1, &arr, &arr+1);
}

$ gcc try1.c -o try1
$ ./try1
140736912750144--140736912750148--140736912750144--140736912750160
$ ./try1
140735606483504--140735606483508--140735606483504--140735606483520
$
```

&arr gives the base address of the array i.e the 0th element address ..
but why does &arr+1 increment with size of array and not by 1 sizeof(int) i.e 4B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> &arr gives the base address of the array i.e the 0th element address

`&arr` gives you the same address as `&arr[0]`, but it does not mean that pointer type is the same. 
`arr` is implicitly converted to `int *`, where `&arr` has type `int(*)[4]`. According to pointer arithmetic + 1 gives you base address `+sizeof(int)` in first case and `+sizeof(int[4])` in the second.

Answer (score 1):

In `arr + 1`, `arr` is an array decaying to a pointer. A pointer to `int`. So `arr + 1` is the address of `arr[1]`.

In `&arr + 1` you take the address of `arr` which is a pointer to an array of `int` of length 4. And then you increment that pointer. And because that pointer is a pointer to an array of `int` of length 4, `&arr + 1` is the address just past the end of `arr`.

Comment: Actually it boils down to the '+' adds sizeof(int) first time and sizeof(int[4]) second time. Precedence is kind of secondary.

Comment: @david.pfx OK. If the precedence was the other way around then `&arr+1` would make no sense at all. I removed that comment.